# Cannot type special characters using Alt+number in Windows

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, special-characters

My Windows 8 machine has recently (in the last couple of months) stopped letting me type special characters with their <kbd>Alt</kbd> codes (e.g. holding down <kbd>Alt</kbd> and typing 0133 on the numpad should produce an … after releasing the <kbd>Alt</kbd> key).  Instead, when I try, nothing happens.

This happens with the laptop keyboard and with an external keyboard.  When I go into Character Map, it still shows the corresponding Keystroke for the characters as it always has.  I get the same result (none) for the three character combinations, too (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+161).  I'm using a standard English QWERTY keyboard (this is the keyboard configured in Windows, and English is the only language configured, as well), and haven't had anything that I know of change language or keyboard settings.  I've also tried with NumLock on and off.

Comment: Verify which keyboards and language packs you have installed and update your question.

Comment: You need to have numlock on when using the numpad to type alt+number

Comment: I've updated the question with those details

Comment: you should enter the numbers with number keypad found at the right side of the keyboard, not with the numbers above the keyboard.