# Alt with numpad doesn't give the right special characters

Tags: windows-8, windows-8.1, special-characters, characters

Using Windows 8.1.

```
Input: | Expected: | Actual: 
-------+-----------+--------------
Alt+1  | `☺`       | Windows ding
Alt+2  | `☻`       | Windows ding
Alt+3  | `♥`       | CTRL+C
Alt+4  | `♦`       | Windows ding
Alt+5  | `♣`       | Windows ding
Alt+6  | `♠`       | Windows ding
Alt+7  | `•`       | Windows ding
Alt+8  | `◘`       | Backspace
Alt+9  | `○`       | `  `
Alt+10 | `◙`       | Newline
Alt+11 | `♂`       | Windows ding
Alt+12 | `♀`       | Windows ding
Alt+13 | `♪`       | Newline
Alt+14 | `♫`       | Windows ding
Alt+15 | `☼`       | Windows ding
Alt+16 | `►`       | Windows ding
Alt+17 | `◄`       | Windows ding
Alt+18 | `↕`       | Windows ding
Alt+19 | `‼`       | Windows ding
Alt+20 | `¶`       | Windows ding
Alt+21 | `§`       | Windows ding
Alt+22 | `▬`       | CTRL+V
Alt+23 | `↨`       | Windows ding
Alt+24 | `↑`       | Windows ding
Alt+25 | `↓`       | Windows ding
Alt+26 | `→`       | CTRL+Z
Alt+27 | `←`       | Windows ding
Alt+28 | `∟`       | Windows ding
Alt+29 | `↔`       | Windows ding
Alt+30 | `▲`       | ``
Alt+31 | `▼`       | ``
Alt+127| `⌂`       | ``
Alt+128| `Ç`       | `€`
Alt+219| `█`       | `ﾛ`
etc
```

From 32 to 126 works fine as expected and some other areas too.

I'd like to know how to change this behavior.

Comment: [I thought this](http://superuser.com/questions/807369/cannot-type-special-characters-using-altnumber-in-windows?rq=1) was the solution but there are no answers and ALT+0133 works for me.

Comment: Alt+30 gives RS and Alt+31 gives US.

Comment: Have you tried it with leading zeroes; e.g., (Alt)+(01)?

Comment: @G-Man Yes but it doesn't help at all. The character set is maybe switched.